# DB query is not getting all records as defined

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

## Model

```
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $q = $this->db->get_where('shipping_address', array('customer_id' => $id));

    if ($q->num_rows == 0)
    {
        $data['id'] = 'You dont have a shipping address saved.';

    } else {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) 
            {
            $data['first'] = $row->firstname;
            $data['last'] = $row->lastname;
            }
    }
    return $data;
```

## Controller

```
    $this->load->model('Customer_accounts');

        $customer = $this->Customer_accounts->get_customer_info();
        $ship = $this->Customer_accounts->shipping_address();

        $data = $ship + $customer;

    $this->load->view('account_dashboard/personal_information', $data);
```

## View

```
<?php foreach ($ship as $row) : ?>
    <table class="fixCap" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] . $row['lastname']; ?></td> 
      </tr>

           . . .

      </tr>
    </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

## Var_dump

Is only showing an `array` with 1 of the the table `rows` but it should be showing 2 rows which contain the defined `customer_id`

## Problem

Unable to pass the all the db `data` to the `foreach` what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `Model` I replaced the above code with

## Model

```
return $this->db->get_where('shipping_address', array('customer_id' => $id))->result();
```

And in my

## View

```
#I echoed the vars as objects 
$row->firstname
```

Comment: I didn't realize my mistake until I posted my question. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$data = array_merge($ship, $customer); // they will merged as one array
```

or you can do it this way if u want them separated

```
$data = array();
$data['ship'] = $ship;
$data['customer'] = $customer;

//In the view
//ship
foreach($data['ship'] as $ship)
{
   //Ship values
}

//customer
foreach($data['customer'] as $customer)
{
   //Customer value
}
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually puling the result from database with your code.

try something like this

```
$ret =  $q->get()->result();
```

foreach($ret as $row)
{

}